# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta SQL elaborada?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, join, inner

Cordial saludo a tod@s, vengo haciendo una BD referente a un Colegio, el cual es solo para aprendizaje, y he estado un poco enrollado al momento de las `consultas.A` continuación dejo mi modelo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mediante este modelo (el cual no esta aun terminado) quiero hacer una consulta donde me muestre el horario de clases que tiene X grado.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He echo las consultas pero me arroja repetido los campos, esta es una de las tantas consultas que he realizado:

```
select d.nombre as dia, f.inicio, f.finaliza, m.nombre as materia, 
doc.nombres as docente
from dias as d, franja_horas as f, docentes as doc, materias as m, 
grados as g, docente_x_materia as dm
natural join horarios as h where g.grado_id = '3001';
```

**Nota:** (el '3001' es el código del grado en la table Grados).

Esto es lo que me arroja, se me repiten por cada hora las materias y docentes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien tiene idea de como hacer esta consulta le agradecería.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si no vemos la consulta no vamos a poder ayudarte...

Comment: Podrias mostrar el resultado que recibis?

Comment: *Join* con coma es un estilo viejo que al usarlo con varias tablas te invita a un revolvedero de datos; es mejor utilizar la palabra reservada `JOIN` y establecer claramente sus respectivos predicados con su cláusula `ON`.

Comment: algun ejemplo? para ver si retomo de allí. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para poder hacer solamente una linea por materia lo que podrías utilizar es MIN() y MAX(), y agrupando.
Espero te sea de ayuda.
Ejemplo:

```
select d.nombre as dia, MIN(f.inicio), MAX(f.finaliza), m.nombre as materia, 
doc.nombres as docente
from dias as d, franja_horas as f, docentes as doc, materias as m, 
grados as g, docente_x_materia as dm
natural join horarios as h where g.grado_id = '3001';

GROUP BY d.nombre, m.nombre, doc.nombres
```

Lo que buscamos es agrupar todas las lineas en una sola, agrupando por materia, curso y docente.

Comment: Mi amigo primero que todo muchas gracias por tomarte la molestia de contestar, segundo te digo que he probado lo expuesto y el resultado no es el esperado, ya que se me estan repitiendo todos los docentes y materias, por ende tambien se me duplican los dias y horas.

Comment: GuerreroEnier; Pueba entonces conectar las tablas a través de distintos Left Join una por una.

Answer (score 0):

Cordial saludo compañer@s, he estado trabajando en mi problema y he logrado hallar una solucion.

```
select d.nombre as dia, fh.inicio, fh.finaliza, doc.nombres as profesor , 
ma.nombre as materia
from horarios h
join docente_x_materia as dm 
ON h.doc_mat_id = dm.docente_x_materia_id
join docentes as doc 
ON doc.docente_id = dm.docente_id 
join materias as ma 
ON ma.materia_id = dm.materia_id
join horas as ho 
ON h.hora_id = ho.hora_id
join franja_horas as fh 
ON fh.franja_hora_id = ho.franja_hora_id
join dias as d 
ON h.dia_id = d.dia_id
where h.grado_id = '3001'
order by h.horario_id;
```

No se si esta es la solución mas optima, espero que si tienen una mejor manera por favor me la hagan saber, ya que quiero ir enriqueciendo mis conocimientos.
A continuación dejo captura del resultado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]